# Is it possible to 'freeze panes' in SharePoint lists?

Tags: list-view, column

I need to keep my column header, so people can see what data is displayed there, but I can not find if it is possible, or how to do it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 great posts which you could check out. Both are implemented using jquery.

http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2009/06/sharepoint-jquery-scrolling-view-with.html

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-for-everyone-aop-in-action-clone-list-header.aspx